# AngularJS, service & promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on angularJS for a bit and I need some help..

Here is what I want to do :

- I need to build a service that will get & store my application properties (via $http.get())
- I want to have several popup using thoses properties (1 popup = 1 directive/controller..)
- I don't want the popups to "see" the rest calls (myService.myData should be enough)

My problems:

- I am not able to make the service retrieve the datas BEFORE controllers call
- I saw some way to do it.. but it needs some application changes (in the app.js), I don't want the popup developpers to do so
- As I can't do so, I am not able to make something clean in my service/controller

I want clients to be able to make their own popups, without caring about how the service call the application.
I know I can do it with regular callbacks in the controller.. but as it is the client role to code inside it, I want this part to be as simple as possible.

PS : Of course I tested a simpler implementation before, with callbacks inside the controller etc.. it worked.. But I need to be as clean as below :

Code Examples :
service :

```
angular.module("myService", []).service("MyService", ['$http', function($http){
    this.propertiesInitialized = false;
        this.availableLanguages = [];
        this.availableResultTypes = [];
        this.availableStates = [];
        this.availableCrawlTypes = [];
        this.dateFormat = "";

        this.getProperties = function(callback)
        {
            $http.get("app/application-properties.json").success(function(JSONProperties) {
                this.availableLanguages = JSONProperties.configurations.crawlerLanguages;
                this.availableResultTypes = JSONProperties.configurations.resultTypes;
                this.availableStates = JSONProperties.configurations.states;
                this.availableCrawlTypes = JSONProperties.configurations.crawlTypes;
                this.dateFormat = JSONProperties.configurations.dateFormat;
                this.propertiesInitialized = true;
            });
        }
    }]);
```

one popup:

```
angular.module("popup1", ["MyService"])
.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', 'MyService', 
    function($scope, MyService) {

    $scope.languages = MyService.availableLanguages;
    $scope.crawlTypes = MyService.availableLanguagesCrawlTypes;
    $scope.resultTypes = MyService.availableLanguagesResultTypes;

}]);
```

Have you got some ideas ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a promise.

```
angular.module("myService", []).service("MyService", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    var theService = this;

    theService.propertiesInitialized = deffered.promise;
    theService.availableLanguages = [];
    theService.availableResultTypes = [];
    theService.availableStates = [];
    theService.availableCrawlTypes = [];
    theService.dateFormat = "";

    $http.get("app/application-properties.json").success(function(JSONProperties) {
        theService.availableLanguages = JSONProperties.configurations.crawlerLanguages;
        theService.availableResultTypes = JSONProperties.configurations.resultTypes;
        theService.availableStates = JSONProperties.configurations.states;
        theService.availableCrawlTypes = JSONProperties.configurations.crawlTypes;
        theService.dateFormat = JSONProperties.configurations.dateFormat;
        theService.propertiesInitialized.resolve();
    });
}]);

angular.module("popup1")
.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', 'MyService', 
    function($scope, MyService) {

    MyService.propertiesInitialized.then(function(){
        $scope.languages = MyService.availableLanguages;
        $scope.crawlTypes = MyService.availableLanguagesCrawlTypes;
        $scope.resultTypes = MyService.availableLanguagesResultTypes;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: My bad, missed it. `this` inside success callback has another context and refers to another object. I'll update answer

Comment: For the otehrs : I removed my comment because I thought I was talking too fast (before searching deeper I mean). The question is quite obvious with the Dida_Uranov comment :). Thanks